# Significance of Incorrectly Written Car Plate in 'Memento'

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, memento

I recently watched Christopher Nolan's 'Memento' and found myself puzzled by a specific detail. There's a scene where the main character, Leonard, writes down a car's license plate number but gets it wrong. This detail seemed intentionally highlighted in the film, and I'm trying to understand its significance within the context of the story.

What was the point of Leonard writing the license plate number incorrectly? Does this serve a larger purpose in the narrative or theme of the movie? Is it meant to reflect on Leonard's condition and the reliability of his memory system, or is there a deeper symbolic meaning to this mistake?

Answer (score 4):

The license plate itself actually changes in the movie.

[image]

This was probably done to show the unreliable narrative given by Leonard throughout the movie.